# Change link_to to a button in a Nested Model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, button-to

Ok i just got done implementing a nested Form from

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

These videos are great but now i want to customize the links and make them look like buttons...

this is the link code:

```
<p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Vehicle", f, :vehicles %></p>
```

and that actually links to a helper method:

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render("shipments/partials/" + association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
```

how can i make this into a button

Here is a sample of a button code that i use:

```
<button id="add_button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 15px;">Add Another</button>
```

I Have tried to add a class to the link

Tried this:

```
<%= button_to_remove_fields "Remove", f, :class=>"btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
```

Got This

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Comment: Instead of making that link as button you can provide a class that will look like a button

Comment: I have tried to add the class will paste ERROR

Comment: paste that code here

Comment: pasted it in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to_remove_fields "Remove", f %>
```

Comment: I did forget the Arrow now i get `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)`

Comment: try to give that class to p tag

Comment: that works please update your answer and i will accept thanks... didnt know i could change a p tag into a button looking element

Comment: try this

.button {
 display: inline-block;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: solid 1px #da7c0c;
 background: #478dad;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font: 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding: .5em 2em .55em;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 -webkit-border-radius: .5em; 
 -moz-border-radius: .5em;
 border-radius: .3em;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

and give this class to p tag